# "OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory" encountered on os.rename

Tags: python

I have a number of image files stored as 0.png, 1.png, ..., x.png in a folder. I have to rename then in the opposite order, i.e. 0->x, 1->(x-1), .., (x-1)->1, x->0. I have written the following code in python.

```
for filename in os.listdir("."):
    tempname = "t" + filename
    os.rename(filename, tempname)
for x in range(minx, maxx+1):
    tempname = "t" + str(x) + ".png"
    newname = str(maxx-x) + ".png"
    os.rename(tempname, newname)
```

I encounter the following error:

```
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong?
Is there a smarter way of doing this?

Comment: Maybe one file in the middle is missing. You should catch `OSError` and print them along with the file name affected.

Comment: I have tried it with just two files, it fails when os.rename is called.

Comment: try to use `os.path.exists` to check whether your files exists or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following, it uses the `glob` module to get the file list. This should include the full path otherwise `os.rename` could fail:

```
import glob
import os

source_files = glob.glob(r'myfolder\mytestdir\*')
temp_files = ['{}.temp'.format(file) for file in source_files]
target_files = source_files[::-1]

for source, temp in zip(source_files, temp_files):
    os.rename(source, temp)

for temp, target in zip(temp_files, target_files):
    os.rename(temp, target)
```

Note, if you want to target just `.png` files, you could change the glob line to be `*.png`

Comment: @Martin .. does `os.rename` requires a full path names ?

Comment: No, but it is highly recommended to use one otherwise you are relying on what the current directory is.