# os.rename does not succeed in renaming in subdirectories, throws FileNotFoundError despite using glob.glob with recursive=True

Tags: python, python-3.x, rename, file-rename, batch-rename

The following code is meant to rename  files named "notes" to "notes.html.pmd" in the cwd and in sub-directories. Those still on Python3.7 and earlier versions need to get rid off the walrus operator and substitute

```
fileListOld = glob.glob(f"{(cwd := os.getcwd())}/**/{old_name}", recursive=True)
```

with

```
cwd = os.getcwd()
fileListOld = glob.glob(f"{cwd}/**/{old_name}", recursive=True)
```

in order to run this code. Anyways, the code is following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.8

import glob, os

old_name = r"notes"

new_name = r"notes.html.pmd"

fileListOld = glob.glob(f"{(cwd := os.getcwd())}/**/{old_name}", recursive=True)
print(fileListOld)

for f in fileListOld:
    os.rename(old_name, new_name)
```

The issue is that renames "notes" only in CWD and not in sub-directories. Moreover Python throws the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./rename.py", line 17, in <module>
    os.rename(old_name, new_name)     
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'notes' -> 'notes.html.pmd'
```

I know that my problem is somewhat [similar to theirs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34085211/oserror-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory-encountered-on-os-rename). Yet, it is different in that my code is meant to rename also the files in subdirectories, hence *recursive=True parameter*.

What am I doing wrong? What is the simplest way to rename files recursively?

Comment: I don't understand why you're iterating though `fileListOld` with the variable `f` but calling `rename` with the same two variables `old_name` and `new_name` unchanging.

Comment: @khelwood I have many files in many different directories named "notes". I want to change the name of all of them to "notes.html.pmd". What do you mean by "unchanging"?

Comment: I mean that going through the loop doesn't change the values of `old_name` and `new_name`, but you're calling `os.rename(old_name, new_name)` over and over again as if it does something different each time.

Comment: In general, if you have a loop like `for f in something:` and the loop body doesn't use `f`, there's probably something wrong.

Comment: Is there a reason for the assignment expression to ``cwd`` *at all*? Why not use just ``f"{os.getcwd()}/**/{old_name}"``? This code seems to ignore *everything* but ``old_name`` and ``new_name``.

Comment: Dear @khelwood, my intend was to do the same task (renaming) on all files. os.rename(old_name, new_name) was meant to do this. I have hundreds "notes" files scattered inside of my home directory tree. That's why I chose for loop. f is meant to represent each file that I want to rename. The print statement, which is there only for the debugging purpose,  shows that the list is correctly generated. Therefore, I assume that something is wrong in the last two lines of the code.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi No particular reason. Following your remark the code:                                       
                                                                              
for f in glob.glob(f"{os.getcwd()}/**/{old_name}", recursive=True):
    os.rename(old_name, new_name)                 
**still throws the same error and renames only in the current directory, not in subdirectories.**

Comment: As others have pointed out, that is because you completely ignore the result of the glob, or for that matter any variable other than old_name and new_name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You’re renaming the same `old_name == "notes"` to `new_name == "notes.html.pmd"` over and over instead of using the paths provided by `glob.glob`. I’d use [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob):

```py
#!/usr/bin/env/python3

from pathlib import Path

old_name = "notes"
new_name = "notes.html.pmd"

for old_path in Path(".").glob(f"**/{old_name}"):
    old_path.rename(old_path.parent / new_name)
```